# How to remove or trim a part of $PATH variable from directory: macOS zsh

Tags: macos, path, environment-variables, zsh

In order to add the ~/.composer/vendor/bin to my $PATH directory, I ended up adding two many of them. So, I want to trim/remove that extra $PATH directory portion. My operating system is macOS Catalina and the shell is "-zsh".

After 'echo $PATH' my terminal looks like this: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mdmuhaiminhossain/.composer/vendor/bin:/Users/mdmuhaiminhossain/.composer/vendor/bin:/Users/mdmuhaiminhossain/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mdmuhaiminhossain/.composer/vendor/bin`

I want it to look like this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mdmuhaiminhossain/.composer/vendor/bin
```

I used this command to fix it but failed:

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mdmuhaiminhossain/.composer/vendor/bin' >> ~/.zshrc
```

it would very grateful if anyone show me how to fix it.

Comment: How exactly did you edit your configuration file to update `PATH` in the first place?

Comment: Your attempted fix just made things worse. Your configuration file *already* has something at appends the desired directory to `PATH`, and then you added *another* statement that does the same thing. Likely, you just need to open `.zshrc` in an editor and remove the extraneous statements that modify `PATH`.

Comment: In addition to what @chepner said note that modifying your *~/.zshrc* will not affect the running shell. You'll need to `exec zsh`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to do this (actually, I stole it from [here](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/7evpdebn7g-remove-duplicates-in-zsh-path)):

Since `PATH` in Zsh is synchronized to the array `path`, the question is equivalent to keep the entries in `path` unique. This can be done by declaring `path` to be an array of unique values:

```
typeset -aU path
```

Comment: Nice link! But may I ask you that after the type of `path` is changed to a unique array, would any duplicate append follows be ignored automatically?

Comment: And what's its difference between `typeset -U PATH`?

Comment: To your first question:  You can easily try it out by yourself with `typeset -a arr; arr=(r e r t); typeset -U arr; echo ${arr[*]}`

Comment: I think you can write `typeset -U path`. Writing `typeset -U PATH`doen't make sense. `PATH` is not an array.

Comment: OK but `typeset -U PATH` works. I'm trying the snippet above.

Comment: @Raining: If you do it (in a new shell) only with `PATH`, but **not** with `path`, and then do a `PATH=$PATH:foo:foo`, the duplicate `foo` won't be removed, because PATH is a string, not an array. Of course if you happen already done a `typest -U path`, doing the same on `PATH` does not harm. It just doesn't have any effect.